# In MIPS Assembly, why is it important to save and restore saved registers that need to be used by a procedure?

Tags: memory, assembly, mips, cpu-registers, cpu-architecture

Why is it important as in, what exactly could happen to the data in the saved registers; does it get deleted or overwritten with new values? Where do these new values come from? If I was unclear about anything, please comment below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call a function, system call, procedure or any other external code from within any assembly language, the function call definition for that function will define for you registers that are required to be preserved and registers that may not be preserved. Often this is documented as a standard for the platform, library or language. You clearly understand this. Your question is, "Why?"

When a register is not guaranteed to be preserved, this means that the called function is free to manipulate and change those registers in any way. It is not so much that they are "deleted," it is that they are changed or overwritten while the function operates; after all, the function must use the same registers that you are using!

On the other hand, if a register is required to be preserved by a call then you are guaranteed that it will be unmodified when the call returns to your code. This may be because the register is not used by the called function but it might also be because it is preserved on the stack (or in memory somewhere) and then restored before the return.